# Ayuda con arrays y sesiones PHP

Tags: php, sesiones

Estoy trabajando en un carro de compras, para que el cliente pueda acceder al carro de compras necesita estar registrado, cuando el cliente inicia sesion creo una variable $_SESSION['Cliente'] de la cual extraigo ciertos datos que previamente registró, si el cliente agrega productos a su carro de compras, entonces se crea la variable $_SESSION['compras']. Mi idea es que cuando el cliente de click al botón comprar, este envié a un archivo php donde se insertan los datos de compras a una tabla, aquí viene el problema.
Quiero que los datos de la $_SESSION['Cliente'] esten en cada $_SESSION['compras'].

Por ejemplo, Este es el arrray que existe en $_SESSION['compras'].

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Nombre] => Kit 2
        [Precio] => 259
        [Imagen] => sese.jpg
        [Cantidad] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 5
        [Nombre] => Kit 3
        [Precio] => 385
        [Imagen] => ripo.png
        [Cantidad] => 1
    )

)
```

Y los datos que saque del cliente que se dio login quedan en el siguiente array.

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Nombre] => Raul Leyva
        [Telefono] => 614-123-4567
        [Ciudad] => chihuas
        [Estado] => chihuas
        [Pais] => mehico
    )

)
```

Lo que yo quiero hacer, seria lo siguiente:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 4
        [Nombre] => Kit 2
        [Precio] => 259
        [Imagen] => sese.jpg
        [Cantidad] => 1
        [Nombre] => Raul Leyva
        [Telefono] => 614-123-4567
        [Ciudad] => chihuas
        [Estado] => chihuas
        [Pais] => mehico
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [Id] => 5
        [Nombre] => Kit 3
        [Precio] => 385
        [Imagen] => ripo.png
        [Cantidad] => 1
        [Nombre] => Raul Leyva
        [Telefono] => 614-123-4567
        [Ciudad] => chihuas
        [Estado] => chihuas
        [Pais] => mehico
    )

)
```

mi duda es como junto de esa manera los arrays. gracias

Answer (score 0):

Juntar los 2 arrays que pones como ejemplo es bastante sencillo, sin embargo si observas, tienes dos índices iguales "`Nombre`". No puedes tener dos índices iguales en un mismo array. Para la prueba yo le puse a uno `Nombre_art`, y al otro `Nombre_cli`.
No usé variables de sesión `$_SESSION`, pero no deberías tener ningún problema en aplicar el mismo código a ellas.

```
<?php

$compras = array(
array('Id' => '4', 'Nombre_art' => 'Kit 2', 'Precio' => '259', 'Imagen' => 'sese.jpg', 'Cantidad' => '1'), 
array('Id' => '5', 'Nombre_art' => 'Kit 3', 'Precio' => '385', 'Imagen' => 'ripo.png', 'Cantidad' => '1'));
$cliente = array(array('Nombre_cli' => 'Raul Leyva', 'Telefono' => '614-123-4567', 'Ciudad' => 'chihuas', 'Estado' => 'chihuas', 'Pais' => 'mehico'));
$compras_size = count($compras);
for($i=0; $i<$compras_size; $i++) {
    foreach($cliente[0] as $key=>$data) {
        $compras[$i][$key] = $data;
    }
}

print_r($compras);
```

La salida:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 4
            [Nombre_art] => Kit 2
            [Precio] => 259
            [Imagen] => sese.jpg
            [Cantidad] => 1
            [Nombre_cli] => Raul Leyva
            [Telefono] => 614-123-4567
            [Ciudad] => chihuas
            [Estado] => chihuas
            [Pais] => mehico
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Id] => 5
            [Nombre_art] => Kit 3
            [Precio] => 385
            [Imagen] => ripo.png
            [Cantidad] => 1
            [Nombre_cli] => Raul Leyva
            [Telefono] => 614-123-4567
            [Ciudad] => chihuas
            [Estado] => chihuas
            [Pais] => mehico
        )

)
```

Comment: Efectivamente funciona, se agradece. Por otra parte, realizar este carro de compra fue una buena experiencia e interactuar con el lenguaje de PHP me gusto mucho pero casi no se nada de el, algún libro que recomiendes para aprenderlo, también se que para hacer sitios web dinámicos necesitas aprender javascript, de igual manera si me puedes recomendar libros acerca de este lenguaje, podrían ser libros de desarrollo web en general.

Comment: @rulo900 en verdad nunca he leído un libro de PHP y no soy tan experto, de hecho ni soy programador de profesión. Para aprender hay que practicar mucho creando cosas concretas y tratar siempre de superarse uno mismo, ir aumentando la complejidad de los proyectos que puedes lograr, la comunidad en internet ayuda muchisimo para resolver dudas. También hay bastantes tutoriales en la red que son útiles. Javascript es muy importante hoy en día, también estoy aprendiendo. Si te sirvió la respuesta, puedes [ Aceptarla ] para que quede como pregunta resuelta.